# "GET method is not supported for this route" even though it's a POST route

Tags: laravel

I have a POST route in my Laravel application:

```
Route::post('/register-direct', 'Auth\RegisterController@direct')->name('register.direct');
```

Currently the method doesn't do anything but try to log the request:

```
public function direct(Request $request) {
    logger()->info($request->all());
}
```

Since this route should be accessible from outside the domain, I disabled CSRF protection for it:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'register-direct'
    ];
}
```

However, the strangest thing is happening. Even though it's a POST route, when I try to send the request from Postman to my remote site, I get the error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

From what I see, it is doing some sort of redirect to `/register-direct` as a `GET` route for some reason. The request never reaches the appropriate controller method (since the logging in the method never happens).

I suspect some middleware is the culprit, but the only middleware on this controller is the `guest()` middleware. And when I disable this middleware, it doesn't change anything.

Additional info:

- there is no other route with the same name or URI
- when I send the POST request to localhost (instead of to my remote site) it works correctly
- the same error appears in Postman and if I try to submit this request from another domain
- I have tried moving the route from `web.php` to `api.php` and nothing changed
- I have other routes in `api.php` that accept remote requests and work just fine

Comment: Instead of using `Route::post` you can use `Route::any(` , any() method can be used if you want to use redirect on the same route.

Comment: I don't want to use redirect on the same route. I just need the post request to actually reach the target.

Comment: where are you 'posting' from?

Comment: @Ballard from Postman. But I also tried posting from a different site I own, with the same outcome.

Comment: When testing from that other site, I didn't use ajax - I literally just created an html form and submitted it directly to the URL register-direct in this app

Comment: do you change your postman requests method? is it post?

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh Yes it's post.